# Travelling to Schengen Area

Tags: visas, europe, schengen-visas, czech-republic, eurail

I need help with the covering letter which is supposed to be used for VISA filing from India for Schengen Visa. Also, I have everything booked except the inter country transportation, which we are thinking to do once we are in Europe. As we might take a car or train or any other means of transport. Can anyone help me as to how to mention this in the cover letter?

Comment: Even if you don’t book them, you should definitely look up schedules to avoid surprises, especially if you are booking hotels. Some routes are quick and have frequent service, others much less so.

Comment: I have Voted to Leave Open. I don't agree that this is too broad. The OP doesn't want help deciding on transportation, but on how to indicate successfully within the cover letter that this hasn't been decided. I also don't believe it is Primarily Opinion. What to include in a cover letter, and how to word a cover letter to cover unknown travel plans can be done in a way that is more objective than not. IMO.

Answer (score 2):

You would need to provide a day-wise itinerary in Europe, with hotel bookings for each of the places you plan to stay in. Mention in your covering letter, that you will buy your intra-schengen tickets locally (your bank balance needs to show that you have the cash for that). In separate annexures, show your itinerary and hotel bookings. If you wish to drive, provide a copy of your International driving permit.